# [actors], [cast], and [casting]

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

Here are three tags that need sorting out:

- [actors](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actors) (32 questions)

  > Actors are the cast members that portray the characters that entertain audiences in live action TV, films and stage shows. Voice actors, also refered to as voice over artists, are actors that lend their voices to radio and animated productions. Actors are also used to promote and sell products in commercials, in print, and on billboards.
- [cast](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cast) (6 questions)

  [no tag wiki]
- [casting](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/casting) (1 question)

  [no tag wiki]
- as well as [a few](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53562/how-did-brent-spiner-get-cast-as-data-for-tng/58455#58455) questions [that](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94125/why-was-jor-el-played-by-two-different-people) don't have any of these tags but probably should.

Now the obvious solution is to retag all the [cast](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cast) and [casting](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/casting) questions as [actors](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actors) instead. BUT WAIT! There's more than one type of question falling under these headers, and it might be useful to have more than one tag for such questions. I suggest the following.

- Questions about the **casting process** (choice of actors, auditioning, etc.) should be tagged with [casting](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/casting). Examples:

  - [How did Brent Spiner get cast as Data for TNG?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53562/how-did-brent-spiner-get-cast-as-data-for-tng)
  - [Was the casting of Alan Rickman as Snape based on the full knowledge of the future of that character?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8269/was-the-casting-of-alan-rickman-as-snape-based-on-the-full-knowledge-of-the-futu)
  - [Is this story about how Michael Dorn became Worf true?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104203/is-this-story-about-how-michael-dorn-became-worf-true)
- Questions about the **actors themselves** (number of roles, [their views on films](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7799/laine-liska-s-and-everybody-and-their-cousins-attitude-toward-star-wars), what they had for breakfast, etc.) should be tagged with [actors](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actors). Examples:

  - [Has anyone played more distinct roles in Star Wars than Warwick Davis?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111160/has-anyone-played-more-distinct-roles-in-star-wars-than-warwick-davis)
  - [Has one actor ever played two different characters from Marvel?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110792/has-one-actor-ever-played-two-different-characters-from-marvel)
  - [Actors appearing in both Star Trek and Star Wars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105236/actors-appearing-in-both-star-trek-and-star-wars)
- Usage guidance for both these tags, and when to use which one, should be made clear in the tag wiki excerpts.
- The [cast](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cast) tag, which is ambiguous as it could mean either the noun "cast" (synonymous with [actors](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actors)) or the verb "cast" (synonymous with [casting](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/casting)), should be abolished altogether.

Thoughts?

Comment: PS: It'd be nice if nobody went and 'cleaned up' these tags until we have a community consensus here :-)

Comment: is there a reason these weren't proposed on the thread with all the others? it's not *just* for deleting tags. (Just trying to keep everything together as much as we can.)

Comment: @MikeEdenfield I haven't fully got my head around the structure of all your meta posts about tag cleanup, so I wasn't sure where this would fit. Also FGitW comes into play - a new answer to one of those posts might get hardly any attention. But if you think I should, I'll delete this and repost as an answer somewhere (you'll have to tell me where).

Comment: In my opinion, your suggestions are clear and straighforward enough to be 3 separate answers in that post (one per tag with rules on what to do with that tag). But if you really think it's better to do all 3 at once, perhaps a separate post is better. As far as the FGitW, I'm *trying* to encourage people to revisit it often to keep voting, we'll see how that goes. It if doesn't work, we can always adapt later.

Comment: The [tag:cast] seems superfluous given your current considerations. I think keeping it simple is probably best.

Comment: I fully agree with your proposal.

Comment: I noticed that the movies Stack uses `casting` when talking about this exact thing (tagged 77 times) and though I know each Stack is unique, the fact that a movies-oriented Stack uses `casting` to identity/label the same question types we are talking about kind of makes me want to stick to the same schematic.  It seems to be working for them; maybe it would work for us?  Note: They *do* have an identify-the-actor sort of tag, too, for the ID-ing questions, but otherwise don't seem to utilize any other 'actor'-related tag.

Comment: Questions with the word 'actor' but without the tags [tag:actors] or [tag:actor-identification] can be found through [this query](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=actor+-[actors]+-[actor-identification]+is%3Aquestion)

Comment: @SQB So you went ahead and removed the [cast] and [casting] tags anyway?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the info you provided, I think:

[actors](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actors) and [cast](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cast) should be synonyms, and [casting](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/casting) should be removed.

[cast](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cast) may seem ambiguous, but [casting](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/casting) has been used *once*, and only just recently.

Another usability reason for [cast](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cast) is that it will be typed before [casting](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/casting). If a new user is *trying* to use it, looking to use the noun definition, they'll get an error if we burninate it. Whereas, if we leave it, and they try typing "casting", they'll see the tag-wiki definition for "cast" and likely see that it's enough.

Per SQB's comment, [casting](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/casting) can be ambiguous itself, when referring to the casting of magical spells (or fishing lines!). Yes, [cast](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cast) could be ambiguous the same way, but I believe there's going to be some ambiguity either way. I *don't* think confusing the noun and verb is terribly relevant, as they're still referring to the general topic of actors.

The tag wiki for [actors](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actors) would be better off not being a dictionary definition of what the word means, but include a little guidance:

> Questions about actors/actresses and voice actors, as related to their roles in Science Fiction and Fantasy works, including the casting process, opinions on the work, history of their role, and more.

Comment: I still think [casting] is better than [cast], because of the ambiguity of [cast]: questions about THE cast = questions about actors. A little investigation showed that [casting] was only created yesterday (by @SQB), and it'd be easy enough to retag all the [cast] questions as [actors] or [casting], and maybe some of the [actors] questions as [casting].

Comment: I tend to agree with this proposal; if I "score" the two tags separately they both score low (partly because of the ambiguity just based on the names, partly because of how specialized they are) but if all "actor / casting related" questions have one tag, it scores "good enough" because the ambiguity goes away.

Comment: If [tag:cast] is established as a synonym for [tag:actors], it will cause [tag:actors] to show up in the tagging box when starting to type [tag:casting].

Comment: I now agree with this point of view, since [casting] can, and probably will, be confused with spell casting.

Comment: Someone now seems to have removed all instances of the [cast] and [casting] tags. So after updating the [actors] tag wiki more or less as you suggest, I've accepted this answer.

Answer (score 2):

@rand al'thors suggestion makes sense to me, i.e. remove the ambiguous [cast](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cast), and retag thusly tagged questions either to [actors](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actors) or [casting](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/casting).

However, I would suggest to only start using [casting](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/casting) if it can be applied to at least ten different questions. Else I would just fold everything into [actors](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actors) which with just a bit more than 30 questions isn’t particularly huge anyway.