# Why did these two similar questions get different reactions?

Tags: discussion, voting

[Who's the largest Marvel super-hero?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172312/whos-the-largest-marvel-super-hero)

[Who is the physically-largest Force-sensitive being in Star Wars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172306/who-is-the-physically-largest-force-sensitive-being-in-star-wars)

These two questions basically ask the same thing. One question has got 5 upvotes so far and the other one has got 6 downvotes so far. Why is that? Why are the reactions totally opposite?

Comment: Because people are voting their bias and for the user. And it's annoying.

Comment: @CreationEdge Yes, it shows that your posts have a positive voting bias.

Comment: @CreationEdge - Voters are people, not robots. They have a tendency to see ill in posts made by those [who they perceive to have wronged them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_effect#The_Devil_Effect). Top tip, if you act like a troll, people will downvote you.

Answer (score 12):

For the record, I [down-voted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydn2C.jpg) [each question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3zfb.jpg) due to lack of research. I would expect your question was down-voted by others for similar reasons.

Furthermore, you asked a [second question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172307/who-is-the-smallest-force-sensitive-character-in-star-wars) asking who the smallest force user was, again with no research involved. While each question I am sure has a reasonable answer within canon, the posts come across as mere whims of thought and therefore in my opinion not useful.

You had several comments on the question asking you to clarify what you were actually asking and what research you had done. **You rebuffed these inquires stating...**

> "*If you don't like the question, simply downvote and move on*"

**...which in my experience is not good way to attract positive attention to your post**.

As to why the other question was up-voted. I can only guess that because a least a semblance of research (acknowledging other large character and stating thing they were not looking for) was shown. It also seems that question attracted an answer quicker than yours. Questions with a quality answer tend to attract up-votes regardless of question quality.

**ETA**

You seem to be now going on a spree of asking [simple, un-researched questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172350/who-is-the-physically-largest-character-in-dc) about the sizes of characters in different comics. I am not sure what you hoping to accomplish here, unless your goal is to attract down-votes? All of this seems to be not constructive at best and actively harming the site by spamming questions at worst. As seen in your [newest meta question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11449/please-allow-me-to-ask-this-question), the system itself seem to think you are doing something wrong. My advice would be to quit while you are behind to avoid potential escalation of negative outcomes.

Comment: [Link to the "smallest" question.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/172307/31394) Also a few potentially relevant meta posts: [Are we really here to solve problems?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1380/31394), [Is “I am curious about X” sufficient justification for asking questions on SFF.SE?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2865/31394), and on the flipside, [Laine Liska’s—and everybody and their cousins’—attitude toward Star Wars](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7799/31394)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Like I said, I am sure the questions have actual objective answers. The argument about "real problems" is from the site's infancy, and while still relevant to the overall scope of the site is not why I took exception to the question. The question is firmly on-topic, and while I had initially voted to close as "unclear", the post was edited and reopened. That is fine, the question should remain open, but that does not make it immune to down-votes. Again, the requests for adding ANY research were rebuffed, it make one question the intent of the post.

Comment: @Skooba "Edited" to make it less clear? It still says based on "volume", that didn't change. Physically largest was really all you needed instead of "biggest"? That seems tenuous, at best.

Answer (score 9):

Let's take a step back for a moment.  The OP of this meta thread *has a problem*: they got downvoted.  Instead of trying to answer the question as asked, I think it would be more helpful to focus on solving that problem.

(Given some of the [other stuff going on](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11449/please-allow-me-to-ask-this-question) with this user, I'm sure some of you feel I'm beating a dead horse at this point, but I think we can learn something here, even if OP does not, so please bear with me.)

Why do questions get downvoted?  A downvote means that the voter feels something does not belong on the site.  **That's it**.  It does not necessarily mean that it was a bad question, that it was poorly researched, or any other concrete issue.  It's just an expression of one person's opinion.

What "belongs on the site" is necessarily subjective, but a good starting point is the [top-voted questions in the tag](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars?sort=votes).  Browsing through these, you will notice they have a few qualities which OP's question lacks:

- They are typically multiple (useful) sentences, and often multiple (useful) paragraphs.
- They frequently refer to specific events, characters, plot points, etc. from canon.
- Many of them reference specific canon sources (films) by name.
- Sometimes, they have direct quotes from canon sources.
- Questions which lack all of the above elements, such as [In what order should the Star Wars movies be watched?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1520/36526) and [Which ship can go faster, the Millennium Falcon or the USS Enterprise?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/155325/36526), are so obviously interesting or useful that people upvote them purely on the premise of the question.

If you want to ask better questions that don't get downvoted, focus on doing these things more.

> But isn't it unfair that the other question got upvoted?

Although CreationEdge has repeatedly denied it, the upvoted question does contain references to specific elements of canon and demonstrates a familiarity with the subject matter which is lacking in OP's question here.  I am disinclined to call this specific instance unfair on this evidence.

But let's cut to the chase: Are votes influenced by the asker's name?  Yeah, probably.  Is that unfair?  Yes, obviously.  Can we fix it?  Not really.

Blatant cases of serial voting are [detected and reversed automatically](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed), and moderators or SE employees can also take action where appropriate.  However, this is not a serial voting case.  Serial voting does not result in a single heavily downvoted question, but a pattern of slightly downvoted questions.  So, to the extent that this case is unfair at all, it is so because this user has annoyed *a lot of people at once* rather than just annoying one person a great deal.

Downvoting people who annoy us is not a good voting strategy, of course.  It ultimately results in a level of [cliquishness](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10195/36526) which many of us rightly view as toxic.  But at the same time, we must not bend over backwards to tolerate problem users.  If a lot of folks are simultaneously annoyed at the same person, *there is probably some reason for that*.  Maybe it's a good reason, or maybe it's a bad reason.  But in real life, angry mobs do not just magically appear when a Disney villain needs a crowd song.  There is a history.  I don't know the facts of this history, so I won't comment on them, but I would encourage the OP, and anyone else involved, to reflect carefully on the interactions which brought us to this point.

Comment: I agree with the bulk of your answer, and good job for pointing out the OP's **pattern of behaviour**, not just the single issue at hand. Having said that: `A downvote means that the voter feels something does not belong on the site.` I disagree, that's what a close vote is for, but a down vote is something different; in fact, `It does not necessarily mean that it was a bad question, that it was poorly researched, or any other concrete issue.` is _exactly_ what a down vote is.

Comment: @Möoz: Close votes are for questions which *objectively* don't belong on the site (for example, they are off-topic).  We're not talking about that at all.

Answer (score 7):

I downvoted your question for a few reasons;

- It wasn't especially clear what you were asking.

> As the title reads, who is the biggest (w.r.t. dimensions, obviously)
>   force-sensitive character in Star Wars?

**I wasn't sure what dimension you were talking about.**

---

You've indicated that you want a [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) answer, but not offered any indication what level of canon you want.

**I don't know if you're happy with EU or just want Disney canon.**

---

As an aside, your question demonstrates **zero research effort.**

Comment: Do you feel that "physically largest" is equally unclear as "w.r.t. dimensions"? How about the contrast between the two question being asked about - e.g. does CE's question show more research effort, or specify dimension or canon level more clearly?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - The other question also has some of the same problems, sure.

Comment: I did absolutely no research. I didn't attempt a Google search. I intentionally didn't specify height, width, weight, volume, density, etc. I picked the 2 biggest guys I could think of and the biggest villain as a counter point. Just an FYI for you, @Randal'Thor And, even though I'm genuinely interested in answers to both questions asked, I will for transparency sake admit that I asked mine to demonstrate that such questions are on-topic, can be well-received, and that the almost immediately closing of and severe downvoting of the other question was atypical and out of line.

Comment: @CreationEdge - You did a modicum of research, as evidenced by your suggestion of a couple of contenders.

Comment: @Valorum No, I did _no_ research. Research is looking things up. I didn't. I picked two tall guys I'd heard of before. I didn't even double-check to make sure Goliath was a Marvel hero or a DC one.

Comment: @CreationEdge - Well, one of the people you picked at random is one of those that I would have probably included.

Comment: This answer is unmitigated BS. It was crystal clear what "dimensions" mean ***and i'm not even a native English speaker***. You can always find excuses to dislike something if you go looking for them. Oh, and this is not StackOverflow. We don't downvote questions for lack of research unless the answer is 100% obvious (what would have been Trivia VTC back in the day) - and "we don't" is meant as in "I can find you 1000s of questions that show no research that have no downvotes".

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - It wasn't the lack of clarity on its own, it was a combination of **all three things together**; the lack of clarity, the lack of focus and the lack of research effort.

Answer (score 0):

Because people on this stack are very much biased by who the user is in how they vote - sometimes consciously (as per comments I saw, not guessing anyone's mind), sometimes unconsciously.

(i myself experienced it both ways, both with getting imho-way-undeserved upvotes just for being me; and with getting serial downvotes with people literally going down my old questions in order and downvoting every one they see on a page slowly enough to avoid script detection. Or, downvoting every new question I post for some period).

It just so happens that for reasons I won't bother elaborating, the ratio of people biased against you as a user compared to "for"/neutral, is significantly higher for you than many other users.

Just to address the "points" raised by other answers:

- The question ***was not in any way "unclear"***.

  It was crystal clear what "dimensions" mean (size) and **i'm not even a native English speaker**.

  This thin excuse not only doesn't work, but flies in the opposite direction of supposed inclusivity of SE, where people aren't supposed to be punished for not possessing a perfect ability to speak Her Majesty's English without any regional accent.
- The question was indeed not showing any research. ***BUT***:

  While nominally it is a valid reason to downvote (especially on SO, to avoid help vampires), it can be easily shown on 1000s of examples that on SFF.SE people do NOT get downvoted for "lack of research" - never mind getting 8 downvotes - unless the answer is 100% crystal clear obvious from a trivial research like first page of a book, or main Wiki page for the topic. This question was nowhere near that (heck, I wasn't even aware of the offered answer, despite my [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) gold badge.
- Not specifying canon level.

  OK, you owe me a new keyboard. And a cup of juice. Don't make me laugh. Do you honestly mean to tell me that there are 8 downvotes (or even one downvote) on every [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) question that does NOT specify level of canon?

  This is just a transparent excuse to find some reason to justify a downvote. Congratulations, [you passed the ham sandwich test](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235983/is-there-an-english-idiom-that-means-you-can-always-find-a-law-to-convict-anyon).

P.S. For the record, this tendency to punish un-favored users regardless of the post's quality was on of the few major reasons why I have chosen to largely disengage myself from the site. So, anyone who sincerely told me "sorry to see you go" but downvoted the linked question, should really look hard at themselves at the mirror and realize they were part of the problem that pushed me out.

Comment: I don't doubt that some people probably downvoted this user's question because they don't like him. That's not a good reason to downvote but it's also largely a problem of the user's own making, noting that they've incurred a ban in the past for intentionally spoiling a major release, posting questions that are borderline homophobic, etc etc etc etc, etc.

Comment: Point 1 is unfair and subjective. I saw the first edit and really didn't understand what he was asking. I don't care anything about the specific user. Perhaps because you're also a nonnative speaker that particular sentence construction made more sense to you.

Comment: I'm not happy that Sachin gets downvoted often, but I'm not surprised. Which is why we need to be willing to address the real problem: [**The OP's pattern of behaviour**](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11466/21267); rather than focusing on the technicality of each individual post of his.