# Please, allow me to ask this question

Tags: support

I tried to ask this:

> **Title:** Who is the physically largest character in Raj Comics?
>
> **Body:** I know that Parmanu can grow in size, but I want to know which character was largest ever shown.
>
> **Tags:** raj-comics

But, the system says that

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because: This post appears to be a duplicate of [Who is the physically largest character in DC?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172350/who-is-the-physically-largest-character-in-dc)

I tried changing some keywords, but I failed to post the question.

This clearly is a different question. Please, allow me to post it.

Comment: Are you planning to ask an endless stream of worthless "*What is the X in X"* questions?

Comment: Huh, that's weird. Are you sure you didn't have the DC question saved as a draft in the system or something?

Comment: @Valorum They might be worthless to *you*, but other people might find them interesting.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Let the downvotes be your guide. They need to be well defined and (at least slightly) researched.

Comment: @Valorum The downvotes are a pretty confusing guide, since [near-identical questions in different franchises are receiving wildly different receptions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11445/31394).

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Reflecting a different level of research, perhaps.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Even though it should have been down-voted at least that user is not spamming similar questions. At this point I assume these questions are not being asked in good faith.

Comment: @Valorum There aren't unlimited number of comics universes.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Nope. DC question isn't in the draft.

Comment: The questions are all on-topic. If there's any issue with the *user's* behavior, though....

Comment: IIRC, there's severely limited ability to override the system for content that doesn't exist yet - the only other question blocker system I know of is completely automatic and cannot be overridden.  Add something resembling context.  It shouldn't hurt.

Comment: @Adamant they’re on topic, doesn’t mean they’re not an actual problem a user is having other than a mindless thought, a bad question, content people don’t want to see constantly asked, or an attempt at intentionally spamming the site.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be now going on a spree of asking simple, un-researched questions about the sizes of characters in different comics. I am not sure what you hoping to accomplish here, unless your goal is to attract down-votes?

All of this seems to be not constructive at best and actively harming the site by spamming questions at worst. My advice would be to quit while you are behind to avoid potential escalation of negative outcomes. As I mentioned in my comment, I am now questioning whether these posts are being asked in good faith.

**However, the system should allow you to post the questions as they are not duplicates. You may want to try to add some information to the newest post to try to differentiate it from your previous post.**

Comment: How does this answer the question, which is about a technical limitation of the system rather than whether people think the post is useful?

Comment: It seems pretty clear that they aren't being asked in good faith. Having received a poor reception to their last two questions of this type (one closed, one heavily downvoted) OP is intentionally courting controversy by posting other similar questions, presumably to get a further reaction and create additional drama

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I'm not understanding the level of opprobrium this guy and his questions are generating.  I looked at the fellow's profile page and the list of questions, and they seem to be fairly reasonable.  "Who's the largest character in [X]" is a useful thing to know for [X] fans, yes?

Is it the pacing of the questions that's an issue?  If you consider part of the SE "deal" is that there's going to be this huge database of answered questions, we should expect in the fullness of time to have all these questions and thousands more.

So, please help me to understand.  If I were a Raj Comics fan -- I'm not really familiar with them -- I'd certainly want to know who was the largest character.

Comment: Hi, you seem to have provided an answer which doesn’t answer the question. This question is actually a technical question about the site’s *automatic* refusal which caused a lock in the system, not whether we as a community agree, want or even like this kind of post. We as a community however do have a right to define the scope of our site. With which we currently strive for researched questions which require a problem at hand, not merely wayward thoughts that might gather internet points. (SE even state they’re looking for solutions to problems.)

Comment: @Edlothiad fair enough.  I suppose I confused myself after reading all the comments attached to the question, which do indeed evince some bad feeling.

Comment: It may be inappropriate to point out at this time, but this same user has received a cumulative multiple years of bans for their “trolling” and has what one may call a “bad rap” with parts of the community.

Comment: Frankly it's astounding that they aren't getting *more* downvotes, something I attribute to their multiple name changes.

Comment: @Valorum - here's a hint. If a name change affects votes, **they are 100% invalid votes that should be reveresed and voters suspended**

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - Good luck proving that that's why people have downvoted.

Comment: @Valorum - there's tons of commens on Meta with people admitting they downvoted based on who the user is. Even *answers* admittnig that. Moreover, you sound like Lucius Malfoy now: "why don't you prove it" :)

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To surely it's at least considered bad form for people to down-vote based on name ... one would think that a post would stand or fall on its own.

Comment: @akaioi - that's precisely what I was saying.